# How to get XY of pictureBox1 after it has been transformed

Tags: c#, graphics, picturebox, scaletransform

I have a list of Points that have been drawn on pictureBox1.

pictureBox1 has been transformed.

Now, I want to get XY coordinates of the point that was drawn as I hover over any drawn point.

When I hover over the pictureBox1, I am getting the XY of the pictureBox -- not a transformed XY.

Can you help me get to the transformed XY?

Thanks

```
    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        int height = pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height / 2;
        int width = pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width / 2;            

        //=====
        //scale
        //=====

        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-width, -height);
        e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(2f, 2f);

        //===========
        //draw center
        //===========

        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 0.5f), new Point(width - 2, height), new Point(width + 2, height));
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 0.5f), new Point(width, height - 2), new Point(width, height + 2));

        //===========
        //draw points
        //===========

        foreach (var p in Points)
        {
            Point[] pts = new Point[] { new Point(p.X, p.Y) };
            Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(pts[0], new Size(1, 1));
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, rc);
        }
    }
```

Comment: _pictureBox1 has been transformed_ Do you manybe mean the Image stuff beieng drawn scaled? You just need to follow the scaling&translating numbers and either do the same or the reversed, depending on whether you have points you want to treat the same or points you get by clicking on the already transformed pixels: x2=x1/2f  - width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a variation to @Vitaly's answer you can do this:

After transforming the `Graphics` object you can save its transformation matrix `e.Graphics.Transform` in a variable:

```
Matrix matrix = null;
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    int height = pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height / 2;
    int width = pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width / 2;

    //=====
    //scale
    //=====

    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-width, -height);
    e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(2f, 2f);

    matrix = e.Graphics.Transform;   // save the transformation matrix!
    ...
```

This is necessary as the transfomation data are lost after the `Paint` event! 
Note that the [`GraphicsState graphics.Save()&Restore()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.restore%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) functions can't be used very well for this purpose, as it only puts the state on the **stack** for using it **once**, meaning it doesn't save these data in a persistent way.

Later you can use the `Matrix` and this function to either transform `Points` with the same matrix or reverse the transformation, e.g. for mouse coordinates:

```
PointF transformed(Point p0, bool forward)
{
    Matrix m = matrix.Clone();
    if (!forward)  m.Invert(); 

    var pt = new Point[] { p0 };
    m.TransformPoints(pt);
    return pt[0];
}
```

Now my `MouseMove` event shows the location both raw and re-transformed:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = e.Location + " <-> " + transformed(e.Location, false) ;
}
```

And to test the forward transformation you could add this to the end of the `Paint` event:

```
e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
for (int i = 0; i < Points.Count; i++)
{
    Point[] pts = new Point[] { Point.Round(transformed(Points[i], true)) };  
    Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(pts[0], new Size(19, 19));
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, rc);
}
```

This first clears all the transformations and then paints larger `Rectangles` at the same locations by calling the transformed function.

Note that this will also work with a rotated `Graphics` object. (Although the last test does not draw the larger rectangles rotated, just moved to the right locations.)

Also note that I return `PointF` for better precision when scaling with fractions. You can use `Point.Round` (or `Point.Truncate`) to get `Point`.

Do have a look the the [`Matrix.Elements`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.elements(v=vs.110).aspx): They contain the numbers you have used:

```
float scaleX = matrix.Elements[0];
float scaleY = matrix.Elements[3];
float transX = matrix.Elements[4];
float transY = matrix.Elements[5];
```

Finally: It is well worth studying the [many methods of Matrix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)..!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Matrix with necessary transformations and apply it in pictureBox1_Paint(...) via MultiplyTransform(...):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt34tx5d(v=vs.110).aspx

Then you can use Matrix::TransformPoints(...) to get transformed XY